# Can the code continue after an error is thrown without requiring a try-catch-finally?

Tags: javascript, exception, error-handling, try-catch

[List of errors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors#list_of_errors)

There are many types of errors in JavaScript, as far as I know only 1) `SyntaxError` stops the current script *completely*, 2) the other types of errors (`ReferenceError`, `TypeError`, etc) stop the current script only *after the error occurs*.

My question is, are there **only these 2 behaviors** in JavaScript when an error occurs (assuming we do not capture these errors)?

My question is because in PHP, for example, the `warnings` allow you to continue with the code after the `warning` error occurs

I understand that I can check it myself, but it would be impossible to check error by error, so **I wanted to know if anyone knows of other behavior that I am missing**.

Comment: Functions can log problems without throwing an exception. There's no list of all of these anywhere, since it's purely ad hoc.

Comment: But if an exception is thrown, you have to use `try/catch` to catch it -- there's no class of exceptions that don't cause the script to stop if not caught.

Comment: I have a another doubt @Barmar, just to confirm. In JS there are "only" exceptions, right?, that is, an error (`Error` class) is an *object like any other*, but as soon as it is thrown with `throw` it is "considered-treated" as an exception, right? My doubt arises because in some programming languages Errors and Exceptions are different things.

Comment: Every exception stops further code from executing (until it is caught). The difference to a syntax error is that the code never starts executing when it failed to parse.

Comment: @jwa Yes, I don't think JS has that distinction.

Comment: Hi @Bergi, an exception is *anything* thrown with `throw`, right?

Comment: I did not know about those functions @Barmar

Comment: What functions? I'm talking about any function that uses `console.log()`.

Comment: "*Functions can log problems without throwing an exception.*" - @Barmar this

Comment: Right, by calling `console.log()` to display the log message.

Answer (score 1):

Promises can also throw errors out of scope. This means the script which *defined* the promise will continue to execute, and then the promise will be executing within a 'different' script.

This code uses the 2nd promise to ensure we still have more script to run after the 1st promise has finished throwing.

[image: throwing an error out of scope]

Comment: Your output IS WRONG